# Pagination and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pagination

People get to the results page via a form they have submitted. Via Jquery the information is being grabbed from the the database and presented to the user.

On the ‘results’ page users can make additional selection which affect their results (similar to comparison sites). Any changes will query the database on the backend via jquery.

Now I would like to add a pagination to the results page. In my option, I have two options (please correct me if I missed options), but I’m not sure which one is the best option.
Both options will have the current page (or selected page) submitted via jquery to the backend to make sure we select the correct results.

**Option 1)**
Execute the same query as in the backend on the results page to define the number of pages needed.

- **Pro**: easy to implement
- **Con**: duplication of queries

**Option 2)**
Execute the query in the backend and passing the number of page’s back via jquery/JSON along with the information on the results page

- **Pro**: all in one place
- **Con**: is it possible? Will send something like:
  `{result_info: data_array, pages: page_array}`

What will be the best option to implement a pagination to the results page?

Comment: what's the difference between "backend" and "results page"?

Comment: By the way, there is a cool jQuery plugin that do all that and more you should look to http://datatables.net/

Comment: A solution will likely be database specific. What database engine are you using?  It is typically best to handle pagination at the database, cutting down drastically on data being sent back to the user and providing better performance.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel, results page is the visual page for the user, the backend page contains all the PHP coding and database queries.

Comment: @Chris, I'm using mysql as the database. My main reason was to cut down information transfer and make the whole solution quicker.

Comment: @Ralf, you simply can't query a database from the visual page for the user. Database belongs to a backend, and only way to query a database is to do it in the backend. isn't it?

Comment: Questions on SO should show the code you've tried, not be just a general request for solutions. See http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option would be to setup the PHP backend page to perform two queries. First a COUNT to determine how many entries there are, then a SELECT ... LIMIT to pull a page at a time.

So the basic backend queries might look like this:

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
$page = intval($page); //Clean the input
$pageSize = 10; //get 10 results per page

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM tbl_name";
$resultCount = mysql_query($sql);

$count = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultCount);
$count = $count['count'];

//Build your query, including LIMIT
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name LIMIT " . $page * $pageSize . ", " . $pageSize;
$results = mysql_query($sql);

//process $results and append the $count value to the JSON returned
```

If you check the MySql documentation on SELECT http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html, I think LIMIT is what will help.

Cutting down the number of records returned from the database will provide the best performance.  Especially if the database is hosted over a network.

On the Results side, you can take the $count value passed, you can divide it by the number of results per page you want and that'll tell you how many pages.

Then your jQuery AJAX calls can request backend.php?page=2 for example.

Comment: You may want to change COUNT(*) to a column name COUNT(id), but it's a generic solution.

Comment: thanks for the help. The query was know to me. It was more a question for me what the best option to use in combination with Jquery was. Seems to be to use the 'backend' option to calculate the page's. Do you know if it's possible to send two variable back via JSON/jquery via the suggested option?

Comment: Yes, you can build your own JSON string and simply echo it. An AJAX call will receive anything that is output from the .php script. Here's a couple of useful links for building JSON code. http://www.json.org/ this is the JSON standard and describes what is valid.  http://jsonlint.com/ this is a JSON validator.

Answer (score 0):

You should never put unfiltered GET parameters to sql queries. This makes sql injection possible. You should make at least an intval() on $page.